# Реализация физики стрелы

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я чего-то торможу. У меня есть вот такая стрела:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я хочу, чтобы ее центр массы находился на правом краю на острие, и чтобы, когда она свободно падала, она наклонялась острием вниз и падала острием вниз.

Я так понимаю, что центр массы задается из скрипта. Я задаю его в методе старт таким образом:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().CenterOfMass = new Vector2(X, Y);
```

Какие значения мне нужно указывать для X и Y? Почему какие бы значения я ни указывал, стрела спокойно горизонтально падает вниз.

Comment: С точки зрения физики, для изменения ориентации стрелы, распределение масс не имеет значения. А вот сопротивление воздуха - имеет.

Answer (score 0):

Как одно из решений:
Каждая стрела должна быть сделана из 2х обьектов - наконечник и тело стрелы. Потом соединяешь их при помощи FixedJoint.

Но вряд ли выйдет просимулировать реалистично это при помощи игрового движка на толковом уровне. Хотя можешь попробовать.

---

Проще всего будет вручную наклонять стрелу по своим личным математическим расчетам.

```
myArrow.transform.forward =
    Vector3.Slerp(myArrow.transform.forward, myArrow.rigidbody.velocity.normalized, Time.deltaTime);
```

Код взят из https://answers.unity.com/questions/14899/realistic-rotation-of-flying-arrow.html

а найден по запросу "unity arrow physics mass center"

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что мне нужно добавить компонент fixedJoint на оба объекта: наконечник и палка и указать им друг друга как `Connected Rigid body` ?

Comment: И что в таком случае такое `myArrow.rigidbody` - это rigidbody чего: наконечника или палки? Одним словом, буду вам благодарен, если вы прикрепите скриншот, если вам, конечно, не сложно

Comment: Я не просто так разделил горизонтальной линией свой ответ -- это 2 разных пути не связанных между собой. Не комбинируй их. А как пользоватся фиксед джоинтами посмотри в официальной документации.

Comment: Ага. Хорошо. А что насчет второго вопроса? Rigidbody чего?

Comment: полной стрелы же. Еще раз - там 2 ответа, они не связаны.

Comment: Возможно глупый вопрос, но что мне дальше делать с этим высчитанным transform.forward?

Comment: все как в ответе - myArrow.transform.forward =
    Vector3.Slerp(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117184/discussion-between---and-andrew).

Comment: Я дал целых 2 полноценных ответа как можно сделать - один даже буквально с необходимым кодом который просто скопировать нужно, и, даже, дал правильный запрос по которому я нашел информацию... Мне не платят за инстукторство обучения азам программирования. Я дальше пас отвечать здесь.

Comment: Но я не прошу  инструктировать:) За ответ вам, конечно, спасибо, но я хочу понять, каким образом мне двигать стрелу и каким вращать. ВЫ мне дали одну строчку коду - я был бы благодарен, если бы вы подробнее объяснили, как ее использовать: где она должна быть?